# LinkedIn shared link image is not updating with custom url

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

while I am clicking  the contents are being shared. but the image is not being updated. I am working in a single page website application.

```
var customshareurlLnkd = 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + encodeURI(globalConfig.main_site_root + '&title=' + data.content.title +'&source=CMS') ;

detailhtml += '&nbsp<a class="sharebtn" href="' + customshareurlLnkd + '" target="_blank">LinkedIn Share</a>';
```

I have tried this link: http://beta.beantin.se/clearing-linkedin-link-sharing-preview-cache/   , but still stuck for hours. any solution ? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To have LinkedIn show preview data in the share dialogue when a user is about to share, you need to set the `og:` tags in the `<head>` block of your HTML, something like...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Source: **[LinkedIn Developer Docs: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)**.

Even if you are using something like ReactJS or NodeJS, you can still set index.html's `<head>` block to contain the appropriate `og:` tags.

You can find out if you've done everything correctly by using your URL with the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/).

I have also coded up my own working demo, which uses `og:` tags to make LinkedIn sharing work appropriately.  Check it out: [www.sortwords.com](https://www.sortwords.com).